# Node & Express - Access files from higher directory

Tags: node.js, express, static

This is my server's structure:

```
index.js
admin
|_ admin.html
public
|_ index.html
uploads
|_ some files...
```

and this is part of my server's code:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/admin'))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'))
```

How can admin.html or index.html have access to the files from the uploads directory?
Because what I'm already doing doesn't seem to work. Specifically, images that originate from the uploads folder never show in either admin.html or index.html.

Comment: Can you show us how you access the image in your html files (admin/index.html)?

Comment: How is this at all related to node.js?

Comment: @KiranMathewMohan: Since Express is a node.js framework, I think it does relate ;)

Comment: <img src="./uploads/image.png">. I've also tried with ../ but this doesn't work either

Comment: @yannis not really because the question you're  asking is of simple image embedding in HTML page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming same folder structure with images folder in uploads and one image `img.jpg`

```
index.js
admin
|_ admin.html
public
|_ index.html
uploads
|_ images
  |_ img.jpg
```

As you are already serving `public`, `uploads` and `admin` folders as static, in html file can use

```
<img src="images/img.jpg" alt="" />
```

Comment: this worked, I thought I had to include the images parent folder to the path